# Can't run /bin/bash... sometimes?

Tags: bash, display, sudo, bashrc, su

I’m on a Google Compute Engine which is running Debian Wheezy 7.4.

I’ve been noticing strange things recently. For example, I can do `sudo bash`. But then, from root, I can’t do `sudo -u anotherUser bash` or `su -l anotheruser -c bash`.

And, even more importantly, I can’t start new instances of GNU screen. If I try starting a new instance, it immediately shuts down and I get the `[screen is terminating]` message. In the instances that were running, I could not start more windows.

Then I found what all had in common: `bash`!

I can do `screen zsh` or `screen sh`.

I can do `sudo bash` and then `sudo -u anotheruser zsh` or `su -l anotheruser -s zsh` but NOT `su -l anotheruser -c zsh`.

Note that I *am* logging in with bash and I *can* do `sudo bash`. But I can't use bash for `sudo` or `su` from root to another user, nor can I use bash for a `screen` shell.

I rebooted. Yes, this worried me so much I actually rebooted my server.

I have no idea what can cause this and I'm a bit worried.

My bash config files (as for as I know they are unchanged from default):

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`: http://pastebin.com/CsjeJBYd
- `~/.bashrc`: http://pastebin.com/YfkAZUv9

bash completion works on the main (login) shell.

Here is the information requested by Glenn Jackman:

```
$ md5sum /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
144968564a6b1159ed82059920cea76f  /bin/bash
md5sum: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
$ getent passwd anotheruser
anotheruser:x:1004:1004::/home/anotheruser:/bin/bash
```

Also I thought of another test. This works:

```
$ echo $(bash -c 'echo Hello, World!')
```

What's going on?

Comment: What do these return: `md5sum /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash` and `getent passwd anotheruser` ??

Comment: I'll add those to the main body of the question. I still think some profile files are to blame. It's the only thing that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

More specifically, it is the line at the beginning:

```
if [ "$0" != "-bash" ]; then exit; fi
```

That line checks if the current shell is bash. If it's not, it does not use bash completion. If I remove the line, I get errors in some scripts that try to use the `[[` command.

This is what I came up with in the end:

```
isbash=no
case "$SHELL" in
  *bash*) isbash=yes ;;
esac
case "$0" in
  *bash*) isbash=yes ;;
esac
if [ "$isbash" = "no" ]; then exit; fi
```

Comment: Please mark this as answered if you have answered your own question.

Comment: Silly rule, right? But ok.